# Removing a custom sublayer from a custom uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need rounded, variable-height tableview cells.

I use the following code to create the rounded background:

```
- (void)roundView:(UIView *)view withRadius:(float)radius andColour:(UIColor *)colour
{
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(view.bounds, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, radius, radius);
    layer.path = pathRef;
    CFRelease(pathRef);
    layer.fillColor = colour.CGColor;
    [view.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
}
```

The problem is that if a tall cell is rounded, when it is reused, the earlier sublayer is still there and although the new (lesser) height is correct, the appearance is that the bottom edge of the box is not rounded. Presumably, the (larger) pre-existing layer is being clipped.

An obvious thought was to remove the sublayer, but I can't a way of doing it. I've tried creating a new cell, without reusing one, but this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: You can just set the cell's layer's corner radius, no need for all that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recalled somewhere that I'd done this before to a button...

```
self.buttonCancel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.buttonCancel.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

and it works here too...

```
cell.textBlurb.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
cell.textBlurb.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom layer property in your cell class, assign your layer to it and call `-removeFromSuperLayer` on it in cell's `-prepareForReuse`.